# How to change directory with spaces in applescript terminal?

Tags: terminal, applescript, iphoto

I'm new to applescripts and I'm trying to automate a process, but how do you change directory through the script when there are spaces inside the directory? My commands should be correct but a syntax error keeps popping up:

```
Expected “"” but found unknown token.
```

Here is my script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
activate
do script "cd ~/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library"
end tell
```

I don't understand where it is wrong. It works fine on my terminal.

Thanks a bunch guys!!

UPDATE: this worked best!!

```
# surround in single quotes
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd  '/Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library'"
end tell
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The are a few ways.

```
# escape the quotes with a backslash. AND Escape the first backslash for Applescript to accept it.
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd ~/Pictures/iPhoto\\ Library"
end tell

# surround in double quotes and escape the quotes with a backslash. 
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd \"/Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library\""
end tell

# surround in single quotes using quoted form of 
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd " & quoted form of "/Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library"
end tell
# surround in single quotes
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd  '/Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library'"
end tell
```

Also I do not thing the tild will expand when you use the quotes on the whole path.
So you will need to get the user name another way.

Examples:

```
# inserting the user name. And surrond in brackets so the name and path are seen as one string before the quotes are added
set whoami to do shell script "/usr/bin/whoami"
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd /Users/" & quoted form of whoami & "/Pictures/iPhoto\\ Library"
end tell



tell application "System Events" to set whoami to name of current user
# inserting the user name. And surrond in brackets so the name and path are seen as one string before the quotes are added
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd /Users/" & quoted form of (whoami & "/Pictures/iPhoto Library")
end tell
```

As you can see there is more than one way to do any of this.

Or just quote the directory part.

Example.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd ~" & quoted form of "/Pictures/iPhoto Library"
end tell
```

Comment: if i do 'do script....' again. it will open up another terminal. What is the command to execute another line of code for something like this: __for dbase in *.db; do sqlite3 $dbase "vacuum;"; done__ ??

Comment: You break up commands with a semi-colon ";" I do not do this that often in Applescript and do not know the method of this well, but results maybe not what you expect.

Comment: So the following would be correct? 

_`tell application "Terminal"
 activate
 do script "cd  '/Users/raymondlam/Pictures/iPhoto Library'; echo '#Running iPhotoVaccum'; for dbase in *.db; do sqlite3 $dbase 'vacuum;'; done"
end tell`_

Comment: Effectively it should work. But as I say I do not use it that much. Also it might be better create a bash script as an executable. And then just call that.